# php if (($ _ SERVER ['REQUEST_URI'])

Tags: php

I want to create a condition for any pages that will be here: / user /
The pages themselves can have any name.

I have an example like this:

```
if(($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) =='/user/index.html') { echo 'class="userlog"'; }
```

But it only works on a specific page (in this case index.html)

How to be?

Comment: Several options, regular expressions and substrings are two that spring to mind

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if(($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) == '/user/' . basename(__FILE__)) { echo 'class="' . basename(__FILE__, '.php') . '"'; }
```

Check the result of global variable `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and use `.php` in the files extensions.